# jQuery .push() not working

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, forms, html-table

```
$('#create').click(function(){

    var metaObj = {};
    var dataObj = {};
    var fields = [];
    $('#tableform').find(".meta").each(function(){

        metaObj[this.name] = this.value;
    });

    $('.datarow').each(function () {

        $('td > input, select',this).each(function () {
            dataObj[this.name] = this.value;

        });
        console.log(dataObj);
        fields.push(dataObj);
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(metaObj));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(fields));
});
```

I have a form inside table. Each row has same input fields. datarow is class name of each row. I traverse through every row to get the values.

`console.log(dataObj);` shows every row of input. But, the fields array only the last object added 'n' times. n = number of rows.

Output at console is here:
[image]

Comment: Put `var dataObj = {};` *inside* the `each()` code block. You could also potentially make your code much simpler with the use of `map()` and `serializeArray()`, but we would need to see your HTML to show you how.

Comment: Oh.. man.. U saved my time. I tried putting var fields = []; inside each. But, var dataObj = {}; inside the each(), just worked

Comment: Glad to help. I added it as an answer for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `var dataObj = {};` inside the each() code block, so that it is empty for the start of each `.datarow` iteration:

```
$('#create').click(function() {    
    var metaObj = {};
    var fields = [];

    $('#tableform').find(".meta").each(function(){    
        metaObj[this.name] = this.value;
    });

    $('.datarow').each(function () {
        var dataObj = {}; // move declaration here
        $('td > input, select',this).each(function () {
            dataObj[this.name] = this.value;    
        });
        console.log(dataObj);
        fields.push(dataObj);
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(metaObj));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(fields));
});
```